# Problems while positioning div on hover

Tags: javascript, css, position

I want to be able to display a div underneath another while hovering a text box. So far my approach is this:

CSS:

```
.place-info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 200px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 500ms;
}

.live_results {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

place_info is the class of the element displayed on hover and live_results is the container on which the div is relative to.

I'm creating the place_info with this code:

JS:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', ".station-code", function () {
    var code = this.textContent;
    var places = myResponse[0][0]['Places'];
    var place_info = getPlaceInfo(code, places);
    if (place_info == null) {
        places = myResponse[0][1]['Places'];
        place_info = getPlaceInfo(code, places);
    }
    createDivPlaceInfo(this, place_info);
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.station-code', function () {
    var place_info = document.getElementsByClassName('place-info');
    for (var i = 0; i < place_info.length; i++) {
        place_info[i].parentNode.removeChild(place_info[i]);
    }
});

function createDivPlaceInfo(elem, place_info) {
    var body = document.getElementById('live_results');
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "place-info p-3";
    div.id = "place-info";
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
        place_info['Name'] + ', ' + place_info['ParentName']
    ));

    var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log([rect.x, rect.y]);
    var coord = [rect.x + 10, rect.y + 10];

    div.style.transform = "translate(" + coord[0] + "px, " + coord[1] + "px)";
    body.appendChild(div);
}
```

With this code I successfully display the div but the positioning is never constant and I've noticed it depends on how far i scroll down the page. 
To understand better what I'm trying to do, try hovering the airport code on the skyscanner page.
https://www.skyscanner.net/transport/flights/olb/zuri/190816/190823?flexible_origin=true&flexible_depart=direct&flexible_return=direct&adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=1&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false#results

Answer (score 0):

```js
var body = document.getElementById('live_results');
body.appendChild(div);
```

```css
.live_results {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

What I can see from your code, you're using .live_results to style whereas in your method you're selecting parent using document.getElementById and this might be the reason why your style never got applied in the first place and it is positioned relative to document instead of parent div.

Comment: Thank you, but the div element did have an id called live_results and the problem was elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research i realised that the method getBoundingClientRect() takes into account the position relative to the window and not to the whole document.
I fixed it by adding the difference given by the scrolling.

```
var coord = [rect.x - 80 + window.scrollX, rect.y - 695 + window.scrollY];
```